# Firebase storage percentChanges() method returns NaN

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire

I am trying to build a firebase storage service from an angular client, which will upload a user profile image and return uploadProgress$ and DdownloadUrl$ observables.

`uploadProgress$` is a Observable which will store the `percentChanges()` value and
`downloadUrl$` is a Observable which will contain the `getDownloadURL()` value.

When binding the uploadProgress$ to angular using the [value] = "uploadProgress$ | async" pipe it returns NaN.

I am able to receive the image link when the upload has finished.

My code is as follows:

*firebase-storage.service*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFireStorage,
  AngularFireUploadTask,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { finalize, from, Observable, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { imageFile } from '../models/file-upload';

interface FilesUploadMetadata {
  downloadUrl$: Observable<string>;
  uploadProgress$: Observable<number | undefined>;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FirebaseStorageService {
  constructor(private fireStorage: AngularFireStorage) {}

  uploadFileAndGetMetadata(
    fileToUpload: imageFile,
    mediaFolderPath: string,
    userName: string
  ): FilesUploadMetadata {
    const filePath = `${mediaFolderPath}/${userName}_profileImage`;
    const storageRef = this.fireStorage.ref(filePath);
    const uploadTask: AngularFireUploadTask = this.fireStorage.upload(filePath, fileToUpload);

    uploadTask
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          storageRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((downloadURL) => {
            fileToUpload.url = downloadURL;
            fileToUpload.name = fileToUpload.file.name;
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
          
    return {
      uploadProgress$: uploadTask.percentageChanges(),
      downloadUrl$: storageRef.getDownloadURL(),
    };
  }
}
```

*user-profile.component.ts*

```
upload() {
    this.submitted = true;
    const file: File = this.selectedFile.item(0) as File;
    this.currentFileUpload = new imageFile(file);
    const userName = this.currentUser.username;
    const mediaFolderPath = `Profile/${this.currentUser.email}/profileImage/`;
    const { uploadProgress$, downloadUrl$ } =
      this.firebaseService.uploadFileAndGetMetadata(
        this.currentFileUpload,
        mediaFolderPath,
        userName
      );
    uploadProgress$.subscribe((percent) => {
      console.log(typeof percent);
      console.log(percent);
    });
    downloadUrl$.subscribe((downloadUrl) => {
      console.log(downloadUrl);
    });
  }
}
```

*user-profile.component.html*

```
<div *ngIf="submitted">
<mat-progress-bar [value]="uploadProgress$ | async" mode="determinate">
</mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`const { uploadProgress$, downloadUrl$ }` is local. It's only available inside the function. You must create it outside as `public`.